# Fetch latest record inserted by SYSTEM

Tags: sql

I have a requirement where I need to fetch the latest record persisted by 'SYSTEM' even it has been modified by multiple users. Request you to help me in building that query.

**Case-1 data:**
 uniqueId-111 --> This record has been inserted by system twice(records-1,4) and the same has been updated by multiple users(records-2,3,5). Now I need a query when I pass Id=111 and Type=I I should get the latest record inserted by 'SYSTEM' i.e record-4

**Case-2 data:**
 uniqueId-222 --> This record has been inserted by system once(records-6) and the same has been updated by multiple users(records-7,9).When I pass Id=222 and Type=I I should get the latest record inserted by 'SYSTEM' i.e record-6

**Test Data:**

```
PK  |  ID    |  TYPE   | USER       |    Date     |  OtherInfo
---------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  111   |  I      |   SYSTEM   |   01/Aug    |     A
2   |  111   |  I      |    XYZ     |   02/Aug    |     B
3   |  111   |  I      |    ABC     |   03/Aug    |     C
4   |  111   |  I      |   SYSTEM   |   04/Aug    |     D
5   |  111   |  I      |    ABC     |   05/Aug    |     E
6   |  222   |  I      |   SYSTEM   |   02/Aug    |     F
7   |  222   |  I      |    PQR     |   03/Aug    |     G
8   |  333   |  C      |    XYZ     |   03/Aug    |     H
9   |  222   |  I      |    ABC     |   04/Aug    |     I
```

Thanks in advance 
RK

Comment: which dbms you are using? and what did you try so far?

Comment: Are we to assume that the `PK` column defines the order?

Comment: PK - Primary Key, ID - id to identify the record, User - name of the user who inserted the record, SYSTEM user automatically insert the record. Date - date on which the record is inserted. OtherInfo - extra information related to a particular record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select with your type, user and id and then order it by the date DESC. The Result you have to limit to 1

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id = 111 AND type = 'I' AND user = 'SYSTEM' ORDER BY    date_ DESC
) qry WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

See sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/16b37/2

Comment: The above query executed fine but I need a query by joining the same table and using Date column to know the latest record. Final result should be only one record.

Comment: What did you try sofar?

Comment: I had implemented this query but during review it got rejected with above comments

Comment: Why you need to join the same table? This query is exactly what you need, based on your question. If it is a simplified scenario you have to be more specifing or you need to extend it by your own

Comment: If this same has to be implemented using programming language or any other DB then this query will not hold good due to ROWNUM. So its always better to get a single result

Comment: You can use this query in a programming language, and it will work with oracle. It is a oracle dialect to use rownum to only have a single result record, in sql server you have to use "Top".